# How to extract mass from the tt component of the metric

Tags: general-relativity, adm-formalism

Given an asymptotically flat metric, what is the general recipe in order to obtain the mass from the $tt$ component? In the case of the Schwarzschild metric it is obvious but is there a recipe that can be used in general?
In particular I need to extract the mass from the following geometry:
$$ds^2 = f(r)(-dt^2+dx_1^2+dx_2^2)+g(r)dx_idx_i$$
where $i = 3,...,8$ and $f(r),g(r)$ are two functions of the radial coordinate $r^2=\sum_{i=3}^8 x_i^2$.

Comment: [ADM mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism)?

Comment: The metric written in the body (v1) of the question is not really asymptotically flat since it extends to infinity in the $x_1$ and $x_2$ directions. So the “mass” would be infinite. What you probably need is the surface density.

Comment: There is no unique definition of mass in GR, see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_general_relativity, but you are probably looking for the *Komar* mass -- most useful here would be an asymptotic expression for it as a surface integral at $r\rightarrow\infty$ which I do not know in $1+8$ dimensional space time. But maybe the buzzword *Komar mass* or *Komar integrals* might lead in the right direction.